# Hiding SQL Server instance across the network

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I hide SQL Server 2008R2 instance? I don't want it to be visible to users across the network.

Is this possible?

Comment: Voted to migrate this to dba.stackexchange. Not a bad question, but you'll likely get a better answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and pretty easy to set.

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand “SQL Server Network Configuration” and then right click “Protocols for < SQL Server Instance >”. Select “Properties”. On the “Flags” tab, in the “Hide Instance” drop down select “Yes” and then click OK to save the changes.

Changes will not take effect until the service is stopped and restarted. Once the database engine service of the instance is restarted, SQL Server Browser Service will not expose this instance of the database engine to client computers.

Comment: MS docuemtnation is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179327.aspx