# Can't bring up "Hide SQL Server" Dialog Box (inside, Pulldown menus are empty)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to hide the MS SQL Server on the local area network. Basically, what I want to do is following these instructions to solve this question/problem:

[Hiding SQL Server instance across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673934/hiding-sql-server-instance-across-the-network)   (solved)

However, I cannot bring up the popup menu in the dialog box wherein this field can be set. In my case, it looks like this:

[image: sql sever configuration manager]

Note that the selectbox/pulldown menu is empty.
The "Force Encryption" option looks the same, empty, when I "pull it down".

I cannot enter this field, and I cannot toggle the value via the keyboard keystrokes.

Can I set it via the registry?

SQL Server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64) 
  Oct 20 2015 15:36:27 
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

The "Sql Server Browser Service" is not running.

I am logged in as Administrator and perform this via integrated security.

Update Sep 2016: found a bug report here. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/747902/configuration-manager-snapin-dropdownlists-are-broken-empty-and-gray

Comment: Do you have sufficent permissions ?

Comment: @hynek-bernhard - yes I think so... I just installed SP3 with the same credentials/account. Edited Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

There exists a [Bugreport from 2012/2013](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/747902/configuration-manager-snapin-dropdownlists-are-broken-empty-and-gray) with status "Closed as Not Reproducible", though.

> ID    747902
>
> Opened    6/9/2012 8:38:34 AM
>
> Posted by Mike C_1 on 11/11/2013 at 9:37 AM
>
> Do not use the version of
>   SQLServerManager11.msc in the C:\Windows\System32 directory on Windows
>   2012 64 bit (possibly extended this to any 64-bit OS?) the drop-down
>   boxes are gray and inaccessible for the options.
>
> Instead use the version in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 as it appears to avoid
>   this issue.

You have to open a `cmd.exe` console,

```
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
.\SQLServerManager11.msc
```

Then the dropdowns will appear filled and be settable.

After changing things, restart SQL Server service.

Answer (score 0):

Its a  very long shot but ... can you try the same steps **after** lowering your UAC settings from control panel **AND** rebooting ?

**(I don't have enough points to post as comments)**